# C# asp net read values from html page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I'm getting the IP of the user that connects to my website and I want to save his country in my database using [this exemple URL](http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=207.46.197.32), but I don't know how to access the information that page gives me from my page.

```
string ip = getUserIp(); //Getting the user's IP address
string theUrl = "http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=" + ip;

var country = "The country from theUrl"; //How do i get it?
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Take it from the `Request` object...

Comment: Do you define the controls in your code-behind? Set the output? Have access the these elements otherwise? Are they standard HTML elements? Are they actually .NET controls? Too little information to provide concise answer.

Comment: You need to show us what you've tried.  This is not a "do my homework" site.

Comment: It's hard to explain something you've never done and have no idea how to do it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't give us much to work with, but you could try using the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx) class to access a url.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string result = client.DownloadString(address);
```

Given that the output is the following, and you want to get the value of Country ...

```
Country: UNITED STATES (US)
City: New York, NY
IP: 207.46.197.32
```

You can parse the result with some string manipulation with [`String.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7h14879.aspx):

```
var values = result.Split(new[]{Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var dictionaryValues = values.ToDictionary(
                                value => value.Split(':')[0],
                                value =>  value.Split(':')[1]);
var country = dictionaryValues["Country"]; // UNITED STATES (US)
```

Comment: That downloads the whole page output, not the values separated in any meaningful way. Not an answer.

Comment: This is a simple answer to a very vague question. Can't offer any more until the OP offers clarification.

Comment: And neither add any value for future readers, since we're guessing the OPs situation - the question (without elaboration) deserves to be closed so others don't think it's fine to pollute the community as well. Even with the now updated question, this meets the requirements even less.

Comment: My previous comment was supposed to read "This answer is **now** relevant to the updated question".

Answer (score 1):

In your code behind or other business layer:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
var value = client.DownloadString("http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=207.46.197.32");
```

Comment: That downloads the whole page output, not the values separated in any meaningful way. Not an answer.